# Issues changing background image of PFLogInViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I've built my iOS app using [this](http://juanfiguera.com/ios-parse-d/) as my starting point. I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views) to customize the login/signup views, in order to change the background and logo to my own images.

I understand that I need to do this with subclassing, but I'm a bit confused as to how I can go about doing this, because the project code from Juan Figuera's "Parse + Storyboard" doesn't exactly have the same format. Namely, `DefaultSettingsViewController` is what seems to handle both Login and Signup, so I don't know how to subclass it properly.

I've tried making a `MyLogInViewController` subclass in my code below, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**DefaultSettingsViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface DefaultSettingsViewController : UIViewController <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>



@end
```

**DefaultSettingsViewController.m:**

```
#import "DefaultSettingsViewController.h"

@implementation DefaultSettingsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        //[welcomeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome Back %@!", [[PFUser currentUser] username]]];
        NSLog(@"PFUser is not current user");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"PFUser is current user");
        //[welcomeLabel setText:@"Not logged in"];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (![PFUser currentUser]) { // No user logged in
        // Create the log in view controller
        PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
        [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate
        [logInViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"friends_about_me", nil]];
        [logInViewController setFields: PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton | PFLogInFieldsTwitter | PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten];

        // Create the sign up view controller
        PFSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
        [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

        // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
        [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];

        // Present the log in view controller
        [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
    }

}
```

**MyLogInViewController.h:**

```
#import "DefaultSettingsViewController.h"

@interface MyLogInViewController : PFLogInViewController

@end
```

**MyLoginViewController.m:**

```
#import "MyLogInViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@interface MyLogInViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyLogInViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.logInView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MainBG.jpg"]]];
    [self.logInView setLogo:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]]];

}
```

Comment: I did created a subclass of both PFLoginViewController and PFSignUpViewController instead of ConfigViewController and they both works fine, you should try subclassing those classes first, hope this helps!

Comment: @JorgeVicenteMendoza And my `DefaultSettingsViewController` will be connected to those subclasses by doing that?